# JSONModel vs github Mantle Frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel, github-mantle

I am building an application that requires a lot of JSON data handling. After going over different frameworks, I am down to **JSONModel** (*https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel*) and **github Mantle** (*https://github.com/github/Mantle*) due to their rich feature set and ease of use.

They are both pretty much similar in terms of functionality like data transformation, archiving, copying, automatic and custom key mapping etc. However, **JSONModel** has some extra out-of-the-box mapping options and built-in model cascading support and **Mantle** is relatively more popular and obviously github support behind it.

For me performance and ease of use are important, so I was just wondering if anyone out there has real experience using them both and can share that, mostly in terms of performance and ease of use please.

I myself am leaning towards **JSONModel** due a lot of built-in key mapping options and model cascading but not sure about how is it going to perform with large sets of data.

EDIT (04/28/2015):
I ended up using Github Mantle since that blended well with my application architecture, plus it has more modular design where you can plug in your own property formatters, core data support, nested models, and what not.

Have been using for close to 2 years and never came across a situation where it did not work for me, no kidding! It plays nice with AFNetworking or Alamofire frameworks, works with Swift. I tried to look for alternatives when Swift support was still little patchy, man I could not find anything even remotely awesome.

Comment: If performance is your primary concern, why not make a simple app fetching a JSON feed from somewhere (say YouTube search) 1000 times or so and just clock how both frameworks perform doing that?

Comment: Sure, can do! just wanted to hear from somebody who has real experience of working with both.

Comment: any results from the tests that you want to share?

Comment: I did not compare the two as such but tried JSONModel with real life scenario and performance was pretty solid so ended up using it as I liked its built-in mappers better. I would still like to do the performance comparison when I have little bit of time.

Comment: @ican-zilb, btw, can we refresh a 'JSONModel' without recreating it  and have custom property transformers?

Comment: not really, you can only create a new instance - that's why the code implements many optimisations including caching of transformers, key mappers, etc. so you after the first time you create a give model, the rest are created much much faster

Comment: thats gonna be a problem as I don't get whole data in a single api call, I load what app requires and refresh only those fields.